# using mysql to count the number of book

Tags: mysql

I'd like to count the conversion rate in 10 days.  how to conduct the table 2 from table 1?  The logic to identify the conversion is if there is impression before the book date within 10 days interval?   eg. for 123 cookie,  the book date is 6/16, the impression is 6/5 , exceed 10 days.  count 0 .

```
table 1
+-----------+------+------+
| cookie_id | imp  | book |
+-----------+------+------+
|       123 |      | 6/1  |
|       123 |      | 6/10 |
|       123 |      | 6/11 |
|       123 |      | 6/12 |
|       123 |      | 6/16 |
|       123 | 6/2  |      |
|       123 | 6/5  |      |
|       456 | 6/2  |      |
|       456 |      | 6/20 |
|       789 |      | 6/19 |
|       789 | 6/10 |      |
+-----------+------+------+


table 2 
+-----------+------+------+------------+
| cookie_id | imp  | book | count book |
+-----------+------+------+------------+
|       123 |      | 6/1  |          0 |
|       123 |      | 6/10 |          1 |
|       123 |      | 6/11 |          1 |
|       123 |      | 6/12 |          1 |
|       123 |      | 6/16 |          0 |
|       123 | 6/2  |      |            |
|       123 | 6/5  |      |            |
|       456 | 6/2  |      |            |
|       456 |      | 6/20 |          0 |
|       789 |      | 6/19 |          1 |
|       789 | 6/10 |      |            |
+-----------+------+------+------------+
```